# How to run command and checking exit status from windows make files

Tags: windows, makefile, build, gnu-make

I am new to windows make files.I am trying to understand a few things. How to run commands (DOS commands) from windows mk files. I ran the following command from cmd command prompt--

```
find testsuite
```

and it gives proper output. Now I try to run the same from windows mk file as follows -- $(shell find testsuite). However, it gives error  "FIND: Parameter format not correct". Is $(shell commandname ...) the correct way or if not what does $(shell...) indicate? Also how to capture the exit status of the command.Adding logline like below after the command doesn't print anything $(warning $(errorlevel)

Answer (score 1):

> However, it gives error "FIND: Parameter format not correct".

This is Windows own `find` utility. It searches for strings in files, kind of `grep` without regexp :-(. So it requires at least two arguments.

> Also how to capture the exit status of the command.

For `$(shell ...)` function it's in `.SHELLSTATUS` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am new to this so need some more explanation. basically what utility does $(shell find ..) invoke ?

Comment: The same as invoked in recipes: `$(SHELL)  $(.SHELLFLAGS) ...`. Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html).